# stroke-dashoffset Animation doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, css, animation, safari, webkit

I have a CSS3 animation I'm working on for my website in which the `stroke-dashoffset` of an SVG is animated. It works fine on Chrome and Opera but doesn't work on Safari or Firefox. On Safari, the text shows up but does not animate. On Firefox, the text doesn't show up at all. It's most important to me to get Safari working so that it shows up correctly on iOS.

I've tried a bunch of stuff already including changing the units, using percentage keyframes rather than `to` and `from`, adding and removing prefixes, not using shorthand for the animation properties, changing various properties, trying different webkit prefixes, double checking that I'm not animating `stroke-dashoffset` using negative numbers, etc and nothing has worked so far. I've looked at every article I could find online and haven't found a solution. I'm hoping it's something simple that I'm overlooking or that there is an easy workaround but I fear that it's a webkit bug.

I've put a JSfiddle below that replicates the issue in Safari and Firefox and works correctly in Chrome:
https://jsfiddle.net/lystroid/2a97ntf1/58/

Here's is the relevant HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
<svg width="80vw" height="150vw">
  <text y = "500px" fill="none" stroke="#e2e2e2" stroke-width="0.5">ABCDE</text>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
text {
  font-family:arial;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e2e2e2;
  font-size: 23vw;
  line-height: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 98vw;
  stroke-dashoffset: 98vw;
  animation: draw 7s ease 1 forwards;
  -webkit-animation: draw 7s ease 1 forwards;
  -moz-animation: draw 7s ease 1 forwards;
  -webkit-animation: draw 7s ease 1 forwards;
  -o-animation: draw 7s ease 1 forwards;
  -ms-animation: draw 7s ease 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 98vw;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0vw;
  }
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 98vw;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0vw;
  }
}
```

I haven't tested the animation in Internet Explorer or Edge.

Thanks for reading!

EDIT: I should clarify that there are two animations on the page. One of them is for the caption, which works well on all browsers. The animation that I'm referring to in this question is the animation on the SVG text that says 'ABCDE'